# Execute powershell scripts through nuget command line

Tags: .net, nuget

I made a native package which includes native DLLs. The package is just like [SqlServerCompact.4.0.8852.1.nupkg](https://goodfood.svn.codeplex.com/svn/packages/SqlServerCompact.4.0.8852.1/).

When I install the package through GUI by 'Manage Nuget Packages ...', everything is fine and the native DLL is copied to Debug/Release folder. Copying the native Dlls is done by a script similar to that in SqlSerCompact.

And I have the following `.bat` file to automate the packaging procedure of `MyProject`:

```
..\..\tools\nuget\bin\NuGet.exe install MyProject\packages.config -o packages\
..\..\tools\nuget\bin\NuGet.exe install MyProjectTest\packages.config -o packages\
..\..\tools\nuget\bin\nuget update MyProject.sln
msbuild /m /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="x64" MyProject.sln
..\..\tools\nuget\bin\nuget pack MyProject.nuspec
```

The above script runs perfectly to get `MyProject.nupkg` (Compiling only needs .Net dlls). However `nuget install` does not execute the copy script in the dependency packages -- so compiling `MyProjectTest` is fine, but when executing its EXE there is no native DLL in its Debug/Release folder.

My question is why the powershell script is not executed when installing packages from command line? And how to deal with it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not supported by NuGet.exe. There is a [discussion on codeplex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/246942) about this and there are some issues, which have been closed, that were raised in their issue tracking system. There is also a [blog post by David Ebbo](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/05/thoughts-on-installing-and-updating.html) about the problems with supporting this feature.

The general problem is that within a PowerShell script you can use the Visual Studio object model so to be able to expose this from outside of Visual Studio and support all scenarios is non-trivial.

I looked at supporting the [running of PowerShell scripts from outside Visual Studio by using SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx) as an experiment to see what was possible. It is quite a heavyweight solution since it requires SharpDevelop to work and not just NuGet.exe.