# How does project item metadata "PreserveNewest" actually work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration, csproj

In my .csproj file I've added the following config:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient.sni\1.0.19235.1\buildTransitive\net46\x64\SNI.dll">
        <!-- This is a workaround to include SNI.dll in the NuGet package resulting from the pipeline in Azure DevOps. -->
        <Link>x64\SNI.dll</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

But, it's been difficult to find documentation on how `PreserveNewest` actually works. I've looked at various Stackoverflow posts, and found [this page from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019), which states under the section for the `None` element:

> CopyToOutputDirectory     Optional string. Determines whether to copy the file to the output directory. Values are:
>
> 1. Never
> 2. Always
> 3. PreserveNewest

It's doesn't really describe how it works. Does anyone know this? By what criteria does it decide *what* is newest? File changed date? Other version metadata? What does it mean by "preserve"?

The aim of the config is to copy the `SNI.dll` file to the `bin/x64` directory, which it does successfully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the verbiage for the "Copy to Output Directory" selection change between locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23503145/why-does-the-verbiage-for-the-copy-to-output-directory-selection-change-betwee)

Comment: I guess `Copy if newer` in combination with `PreserveNewest` clears it up a bit. I can make an educated guess that it'll copy the referenced file only if it's newer than the one it already has. Would have liked to see it in the docs, but don't know if I'll spend more time on it now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is based on file modification timestamps. Even looking at [the responsible source code](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/e8c17c128ed847d4acd278b42a02df9621bd1652/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets#L4642-L4666) is a bit obscure since MSBuild uses Inputs/Outputs of targets to determine if a part of the build logic needs to be executed.

So if you modify the source file on disk, the next MSBuild run will compare the timestamp to the timestamp of the expected file in the output directory and will only execute that logic if the destination file is missing or has the same or a newer modification date.

This means that it is preferably to select `PreserveNewest` if you don't expect the file to change in the target directory (e.g. database file that is modified when the app is started) over `Always` for two reasons:

- Less disk IO needed to copy possibly large files
- VS Project system will not consider projects "up to date" if it has any item set to `Always` - which means a "Build"/"Run" in VS will always invoke MSBuild and not skip a project if it knows that no files have changed.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the one option you need - CopyIfDifferent - doesn't exist. So if you use PreserveNewest and for example roll back your VCS history, you might end up using the wrong files.