# How can I use a NuGet package to distribute an executable

Tags: .net, process, nuget, exe

We have several non-.NET exes (e. g. PhantomJs) which we execute from our .NET web applications via the `Process` class.

I'd like to wrap these exes into NuGet packages so that they can be reliably located in different environments (web apps, console apps, and unit tests) without having to pre-place each potentially required version in some magic location on the each machine.

Is there a recommended approach for doing this in NuGet?

One way that works but seems kind of clunky is to embed the EXE as a resource in a wrapper .NET dll, and then extract it to the file system at runtime. I'm wondering if there's a simpler approach.

Comment: NuGet is for development time package management. I don't think you should force it to support deployment or even runtime scenarios.

Comment: @LexLi while I can understand this philosophy, many NuGet packages already do this kind of thing today (e. g. "installing" javascript or CSS).

Comment: @LexLi can you suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 10):

You could add the executable to the `content` folder of the NuGet package. When the package is installed on a project, the executable will then appear as a file in the project. From the [NuGet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package):

> Files in the `content` folder are copied to the root of your application
> when the package is installed.
>
> **Think of the *Content* folder as the root
> of your target application.** For example, if I want a package to add an
> image in the `/images` directory of the target application, make sure to
> place the image in the `Content/images` folder of the package.

You could then add a `install.ps1` script to the NuGet package to configure the project to copy the executable file to the output directory, as described in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package).

Comment: This works for packages.config, but not for modern PackageReference scenarios unfortunately