# Make a NuGet package copy content files to the output folder of parent project during build

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to compose a NuGet package containing my assembly and it's required data files.

What I would like to happen is when the parent project referencing my NuGet package is built, the data files from my package are copied to the output directory of the parent project.

This sounds straight forward but if I flag the data files as *content* in my package project they're just added to the parent project on install but not automatically copied on build.

I would like to do this with a custom .targets file in my package if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set content files to "copy local : always" in a nuget package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package)

Comment: See here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30316946/1730559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161498/2687006)

From my experience you can do this only with install.ps1. Modify these files tags - add a `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>` child

You can do it either with plain XML either with NugetPowerTools