# How to change the properties of all the files of a folder to "Copy Always" automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, settings

I want to change the properties of all the files of a folder to "Copy Always". Currently I'm changing the property manually in Visual Studio(2013 Proffessional) like follows:

[image]

When a new file is added to that folder then the *Copy to Output Directory* value is "Do not copy" which is the default. I want it to automatically change  to "Copy Always" every time when a new file is added to that folder.

FYI: I am keeping the DB script files within that folder which needs to be available during auto-deployment.

Any help how to achieve this? Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try marking the folder as copy always ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But that option is not available for folder.

Comment: You can create a custom build action or a Powershell script , Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package) .

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your project file (.csproj) like this (using the `**`):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="YourFolder\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```