# How do I include a text file alongside my class library in my NuGet package which Visual Studio 2017 is creating for me?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017, csproj

My text file is in my class library project. I have its Build Action set to Content and Copy to Output Directory set to Copy if newer, so the .csproj has a section like:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="MyFile.txt">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

I'm doing this because I need to use the text file from my class library, and can't have it as an embedded resource because I want to allow end-users to edit it. When I use VS 2017 to create the package it gives me a .nuspec with a section like this:

```
<contentFiles>
  <files include="any/net46/MyFile.txt" buildAction="Content" />
  <files include="any/netstandard1.3/MyFile.txt" buildAction="Content" />
</contentFiles>
```

Then when I reference the package from another project, MyFile.txt appears at the root of the project with Build Action set to Content but Copy to Output Directory set to Do not copy. I just want the file to be included alongside the .dll, without being included in the referencing project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will create a nuget package that persists your chosen file(s) alongside your package's dll when a consuming application installs it and can be done entirely through the Visual Studio 2017 IDE.

Let's pretend you have a C# project called **Foo.Bar** in your solution that you would like to build into a nuget package:

In Visual Studio, right-click the project `Foo.Bar > Properties` and go to the `Package` tab. Make sure the value for `Package id:` is `Foo.Bar`.

Create a `Foo.Bar.targets` file in the same directory as your `Foo.Bar.csproj` file with the following content:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\MyFile.txt">
      <Link>MyFile.txt</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Right click the project in Visual Studio 2017, and select `Edit Foo.Bar.csproj`. Put the following block in the opened project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="MyFile.txt">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
    </None>
    <None Include="Foo.Bar.targets">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now when you right click the project and select `Pack` (or if you run `dotnet pack` from the command line in the directory where your project resides), it will generate a `.nupkg` file for your `Foo.Bar` project. `MyFile.txt` and `Foo.Bar.targets` will be in the `build` folder inside of it.

As a test I installed it into a sample Console App project. After doing so, `MyFile.txt` is present in the Solution Explorer of the Console App and can be opened and edited. Furthermore, if I publish the console app, both `Foo.Bar.dll` and `MyFile.txt` are in the `bin > Release > [TargetFramework] > publish` folder of the published files (if published using a Folder Profile to local disk).

An interesting thing to note is that at time of writing, if you right click `MyFile.txt` in the Console App that installed the package and select `Properties`, you'll see that `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Always`. If I try to change it to `Do Not Copy` or anything else, it will revert back to `Always` when the dialog is closed despite clicking `OK`. It will act as if you click `Cancel` every time. This is because of the edit made to the original `Foo.Bar.csproj` file that produced the nuget package, specifically: `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>`.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling a bit with the exact configuration of my csproj file. Is there any information available?

Comment: My above answer utilized some of the example provided in the "Including Content in package" section of the following page: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Adding-nuget-pack-as-a-msbuild-target. As for my answer above, the csproj file to become a nuget package needs the ItemGroup node one level down inside the Project node (when you right-click the csproj in visual studio and select "Edit .csproj").

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep .nuspec, then you can edit it manually and add `copyToOutput="true"` attribute.

If you're using VS2017 and want to edit your .csproj, then you should be able to specify extra metadata in your .csproj file (and you can set custom build action if necessary):

```
<Content Include="MyFile.txt">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
    <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
</Content>
```

Comment: As far as I can remember I tried these kinds of things and they didn't work me. I used the following workaround, if anyone needs one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30386836/1676558