# change root folder when creating a nuget package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package from a web project (.Net) using VS2017 and _CreateNewNuGetPackage. All the files are put in the /content folder. The problem when installing the NuGet package in a project, is that all the files will be installed in the root folder.

What I really want is to have a Nuget package where **all** the build files are in content/extraFolder/.

I tried using the  tag options in the .nuspec file, but .nuspec adds files from the project and not the build files.

After that i tried setting the build path to bin\extraFolder and using the option "Nuget pack xxx -BasePath ..\ xxx", but it looks like nuget uses the vbproj file and ignores the basepath option.

I know it is possible to nuget install -outputdir extraFolder/ but i would like to make it easy for the users of the nuget package.

The nuget package I want is something like:

```
content/
  extraFolder/
    all build folders and files
lib/
  dll file
```

The only thing missing right now is the **extraFolder**. Does anybody know how i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really want is to have a Nuget package where all the build files are in content/extraFolder/.

If I understand you correctly, you can try to change the `target="content"` in the `.nuspec` file to `target="content\content\extraFolder"`. So your `.nuspec` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyTestPackager</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="Test.xml" target="content\content\extraFolder\Test.xml" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then when you pack this `.nuspec` file, you will got the following package:

[image]

Add this package to the project, all the build files are in content/extraFolder/:

[image]

If I am not understand your question correct, please add to screenshot about your current status and what you want directly.

**Update:**

> The part i do not know anything about is the part where MSBuild puts
>   the builded files in the 'bin' folder

If you want put those files in the `\bin` folder, you need add a `.target` file in the `\build` folder to copy those files to the bin folder:

The content of the `.targets` file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(ProjectDir)content\extraFolder\test.txt">
     <Link>test.txt</Link>
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In the nuspec file, add the .targets file to the build folder:

Check the [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747744/how-can-i-set-the-copy-to-output-directory-property-in-my-nuspec-file/44752745#44752745) for more details.

Comment: I know this part, but then i can only do this with unbuild files. The part i do not know anything about is the part where MSBuild puts the builded files in the 'bin' folder and where _CreateNewNuGetPackage puts those files in the content folder. Somewhere in this automatic process I need to add the extraFolder, because the web files are removed afterwards and only the nupkg and dll files remain in the bin folder.

Comment: @FritsBecker, Check if the the updated answer useful?

Comment: @FritsBecker, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Thank you for finding this out :)