# Why is nuget not adding my file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nuget-spec

I have this nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Package</id>
    <version>1.0.1.7</version>
    <title>My Package</title>
    <authors>My name</authors>
    <owners>Mu author</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Release note</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2017</copyright>
    <tags>tag1 tag2</tags>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="myFile.config" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="myFile.config" target=""/>
  </files> 
</package>
```

When I pack this nuspec file, my nupkg file is created and in the NuGet Package Explorer I see that myFile.config is included in my package. All well so far.

But, then, when I install this package, the dll is added to references, but myFile.config is not added to the solution.

Things I've tried without success:
- View the folder on Disk to see if myFile.config is created (not there)
- `<file src="myFile.config" target="."/>`
- `<file src="myFile.config" target=".\"/>`

I also want the file to set `Copy to Output Directory`: `Copy always`.

What am I missing here?

PS: I am working on a private nuget server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target needs to be `content` since files of the nugpkg's content subdirectory are copied to the consuming project.

Note that this only works for projects using the `packages.config` style of referencing NuGet packages. For `PackageReference` (available in VS 2017, default for .NET Core / ASP.NET Core / .NET Standard projects), there is a new `contentFiles` feature that includes files logically in the build process.

See NuGet's [documentation on including content files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#including-content-files) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I thought that `Content` is a physical directory of the consuming project. Do you also know why it doesn't set the `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always`?

Comment: Because that is unsupported. I recommend this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386836/784387 (should work for both `packages.config` and `PackageReference` projects)

Comment: Ah, too bad. Thanks anyway!