# Use NuGet contentFiles to copy a file to build output directory

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, csproj

I need my NuGet package to add a file to a project and set its *"Copy to Output Directory"* flag.

So far, I'm using `install.ps1` script, as seen in the [answer by @workabyte to Set content files to “copy local : always” in a nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143817/850848#26129606).

But I've understood that NuGet 3.3 and newer has a native support using its [`contentFiles` model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files).

My understanding was that I create a directory structure like:

```
contentFiles\
  any\
    any\
      image.png
```

And then in my `.nuspec`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    ...
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*.png" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When the package is compiled, the `image.png` with its directory structure is added to the `.nupkg`.

But, when I install the package in Visual Studio (2017), the `image.png` is not even added to the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `contentFiles` feature is supported only when using the `PackageReference` "style" of referencing NuGet packages. It does not work for projects using `packages.config` (not that there is no migration path at the time of writing other than uninstalling all packages, changing the type and installing all of them again).

See NuGet's blog post ["NuGet is now fully integrated into MSBuild"](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html), especially the section "What about other project types that are not .NET Core?" for instructions on how to set the preferred way of referencing NuGet packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the `PackageReference` a VS 2017 thing only? In older versions `packages.config` is only ever used, right? (maybe unless  you explicitly install never version NuGet addon). Also, it seems that with `PackageReference`, the `install.ps1` is not executed, is that correct?

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question [Prevent duplicating files in NuGet content and contentFiles folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47468941/850848). Can you take a look?