# Prevent duplicating files in NuGet content and contentFiles folders

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

My NuGet package needs to deliver some rather large files to build output directory.

In an old NuGet model, such files have to be stored in `content` folder of the `.nupkg`. While in a [new model introduced in NuGet 3.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/nuget-contentfiles-demystified/), such files have to be stored in [`contentFiles` folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-content-files).

To maintain a compatibility with older versions of NuGet and mainly with [`Package.config` package management format](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild/), I need to duplicate the files into both folders. That unfortunately almost doubles a size of the package.

Is there a way to prevent that? Can I somehow link `contentFiles` to `content` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to output the file to the build output (`content` only copies the file to the output directory but does cause it to be set as copy to output directory item), you can use a completely different approach by creating an msbuild file that will be included in the project.

You can do this by putting both the file - say `test.jpg` into the `tools` folder (you could also use `build`) and add a `Your.Package.Id.targets` file to the `build` folder (the name being the package id of your package with `.targets` as extension) with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\test.jpg">
      <Link>test.jpg</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This target will be automatically imported into the project files regardless of which "style" of NuGet reference is used (`packages.config`, `PackageReference`) and should be backwards compatible to older versions of VS as long as they support NuGet and ToolsVersion `4.0`.

The `Link` metadata denotes where in the output / publish directories the file will end up. You could set it to e.g. `defaultContent\images\foo.jpg` to create a nested structure and rename the file. (you could even use MSBulid variables to use some of the referencing project's configuration). The `Visible` metadata prevents the solution explorer from showing the full relative path to the file, which could end up in lots of nested `..` nodes. The `CopyToPublishDirectory` applies to .NET Core / ASP.NET Core apps or SDK-based projects using the `Publish` target for publishing.

Note that you can set the `Inclue`-path to anything depending on where in your package the file is. You can also use wildcards (but then set `Link` to `%(Filename)%(Extension)`)

Answer (score 10):

Found updated documentation describing this in detail at
[MSBuild targets for NuGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package).

> By default, everything gets added to the root of the `content` and `contentFiles\any\<target_framework>` folder within a package and preserves the relative folder structure, unless you specify a package path:
>
> ```xml
> <Content Include="..\win7-x64\libuv.txt">
>   <Pack>true</Pack>
>   <PackagePath>content\myfiles\</PackagePath>
> </Content>
> ```
>
> If you want to copy all your content to only a specific root folder(s) (instead of `content` and `contentFiles` both), you can use the MSBuild property `ContentTargetFolders`, which defaults to "content;contentFiles" but can be set to any other folder names. Note that just specifying "contentFiles" in `ContentTargetFolders` puts files under `contentFiles\any\<target_framework>` or `contentFiles\<language>\<target_framework>` based on `buildAction`.

Comment: That's the way it worked for me, while solution of @martin-ullrich still gave me content + contentfiles