# Showing NuGet package item added using .targets file in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Based on this question: [Prevent duplicating files in NuGet content and contentFiles folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47468941/850848), I'm using `build/Project.targets` file of my NuGet package to add some files to project build output. Like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\test.jpg">
      <Link>test.jpg</Link>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now, I actually want those files to be visible in *Solution Explorer*, so that developer can tweak item properties. But setting the `<Visible>` tag to `true` makes no effect. Is this even possible?

---

I'd be happy even with a completely different approach that still allows the NuGet package to add files to project build output for both `packages.config` and `PackageReference` formats, yet show the files in *Solution Explorer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Showing NuGet package item added using .targets file in Solution Explorer

I am afraid you could not do such things by using `.targets` file. That because when you add item by using `.target` file, this item was added to your project like "Add As Link". That means this item hasn't really been added to your project. So it is not show in Solution Explorer.

To resolve this issue, you can create two nuget packages, using nuget `content` for `packages.config` formats and `contentFiles` for `PackageReference` formats.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I was afraid of that too. Though I'm still hoping for some creative solution. It would be sad, if I have to accept your answer eventually :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, This is indeed a painful thing. I have the similar question as you before, add a item to the solution explorer for `nuget content` and `contentFiles` formats in one nuget package. But I didn't implement it, and discuss with others, finally, we have to use two packages, if we do not want to release a nuget package which including duplicate the files. :(.