# is there a way of making use of .json configurations in .net core class library instead of a .config file

Tags: c#, .net-core, app-config, class-library, appsettings

I have a class library i want end up packaging into a nuget package, i have some configurations i wish to use which are in a `json` file (`apsettings.json`).

I have added this file to my class library project, and at the moment i just want to read the values in the configurations in a constructor without using a `.config` file, i will like to use a `.json` similar to how i'll do it in a web project.

I am trying something like this, but i get an error stating that the settings.json file does not exist in `\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0`. It is not in that folder, it is in the root of my project.

```
    public TokenGenerator()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json");
        _configuration = builder.Build();

        _tokenServiceSettings = new TokenServiceSettings()
        {
            Audience = _configuration.GetSection("JwtBearer:Audience").Value
        };
    }
```

**At the moment, i have just hard coded the directory as a string inside the SetBasePath method**

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to your project's root folder?

Comment: If I understand your end goal correctly, see the answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143817/set-content-files-to-copy-local-always-in-a-nuget-package/30386836#30386836

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a library that other teams might use in other projects, you should not bind it to another package (`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`) just for configuration.

You should have your own Option class which is a simple class with bunch of properties

```
public class TokenServiceOptions
{
    public TokenServiceOptions()
    {
        Audience = "Audience_Default_Value!";
    }

    public string Audience { set; get; }
    public string OtherOption1 { set; get; }
    public string OtherOption2 { set; get; }
    ///
}
```

and let your library users pass an instance of `TokenServiceOptions` to your method.

It should not be important to a library how options are gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is in a library, this class cannot know where and what json file to read.

- Pass the full path to the file to the library or,
- Pass a structure as an argument to the library so the calling assembly can pass in the data and store it anywhere and any way it likes or
- Get the location of the CallingAssembly (Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location) and construct a relative path to that.